# Define the recursive sequence {$a_n$} by putting $a_1 =0 $ and $ a_{n+1} = (\frac{1}{4})^{a_n} $, $n\ge 1$

Tags: real-analysis

Define the recursive  sequence {$a_n$} by putting $a_1 =0 $ and $ a_{n+1} = (\frac{1}{4})^{a_n} $,  $n\ge  1$

my solution : $,a_{n+1} = a_n = l $ ,$  l = (\frac{1}{4})^{l} $,

$  l - (\frac{1}{4})^{l}= 0 $

Now i can not proceed  Further  as  how  i can find the  value  of  l ??

Pliz  help me.....

Any hints/ solution will be appreciated

Comment: `a_n+1 = a_n = l` You need to first prove that the limit `l` exists i.e. that the sequence converges. `how i can find the value of l` Look for a small semi-obvious `l` that works, then prove it is the only solution.

Comment: okks @dxiv    let me  thinks  more....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the first terms of the sequence are $0,1,1/4,1/4^{1/4},1/4^{1/4^{1/4}}, etc.$ I will prove it converges using a special case of *Banach's fixed-point theorem*, in other words, I'll state without proof that

*Given $g$ continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$ such that $g([a,b]) \subset [a,b]$ and $\lambda=\sup_{a\leq x \leq b}|g'(x)|<1$, then $x=g(x)$ has a unique solution $\alpha$ in $[a,b]$ and for any choice of $x_0$ in $[a,b]$, with $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$, $n\geq 0$, the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to $\alpha$.*

In our case, $g(x)=1/4^x$ and $[a,b]=[1/4,1]$ and it can be shown that all the hypotheses are met (please, verify this). Hence your sequence converges to the only solution of $1/4^x=x$ in the interval $[1/4,1]$, which by a short inspection turns out to be $x=1/2$.